# if else simplification in python3.6 with multiple cases

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a condition where user I have a[]. P is a file which has all the variables l, m, n .... which are populated.

then

```
if a[1]  = '1':
   p.l = a[2]
elif a[1] = '2':
   p.m = a[2]
elif a[1] = '3':
   p.n = a[2]
```

these conditions keep going till 20-25 of them

What is the best way to handle this in both python 3.6 and python 2.7

Additional info

Hi, 
Sorry for the undetailed explanation.
l,m,n,etc there are many other variables . But i will have to define them as and when needed. how every 1,2,3, and etc there might be upto 10-15 , it depends , but they are fixed as in those numbers will not change, but l,m,n are something I defined so can be modified.

Point is suppose I get a string like "Hi how are you" and "Hello how are you" then I put this string in variable say 'a'.
then I split the string to a[] = ['Hi','How','Are','You'] and a[] = ['Hello','How,'Are','you']. Two separate times
Now I read the

```
if a[1] = 'HI':
      p.l = a[2]
elif a[1] = 'Hello':
     p.m = a[2]
elif a[1] = 'How':
    p.n = a[2]
```

So here depending on a[1] value I need to store the a[2] value in different variable. 
Also a[1] might have 20-25 different inputs comming.
depending on the input I will have to store it in that particular variable.

Comment: are there only those 3 variables `l`, `m`, `n` or does the `P` file have 20-25 more different variables? If only the 3 variables `l`, `m`, and `n`, how are the next, few subsequent variables in the 20-25 defined? Do `l`, `m`, and `n` recycle for `'4'`, `'5'` and `'6'`, etc?

Comment: Hi, 
Sorry for the undetailed explanation.

Comment: Hi, that's okay. Only I didn't understand, maybe the answers below do what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary to hold the names of the attributes together with `setattr` to set the attribute.

```
lookup = {'1': 'l', '2': 'm', '3': 'n'}
key, value = a[1], a[2]
attribute = lookup[key]
setattr(p, attribute, value)
```

Comment: A map in Python is called a dictionary. Still a good answer though.

Answer (score 0):

For things like this, I like to use a dict as a sort of dispatch table.

You can define a map that looks like this:

```
set_map = {
   '1': "l",
   '2': "m",
   '3': "n"
}
```

and then encode your conditional logic as a dictionary lookup:

```
setattr(p, set_map[a[1]], a[2])
```

`setattr` is short of 'set attribute'.  It takes as arguments an object, an attribute name, and a value.

The way it works is by first resolving the values of `a` and then resolving the values of `set_map[a[1]]`, which will be one of our letters (`'l'`, `'m'`, or `'n'`).  It then sets the property of the object with the value.

For an example, assume that `a[1] = '1'` and `a[2] = 5`, our dictionary lookup would yield

```
set_map[a[1]] == set_map['1'] == 'l'
```

which then `setattr` would resolve to

```
setattr(p, 'l', 5)
```

which is equivalent of typing

```
p.l = 5
```

Comment: That assigns to the set but not to `p.x`.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. I usually do with with function pointers, it didn't translate to attributes as fluidly.

Comment: Can you please explain what it is doing in the above code. 
Thank you
Rocky

Comment: I've added some more explanation in the answer body.  please let me know if this helps. Is there anything else I could explain?

Comment: Why is a[2] = 5 isn't it equal to 'm'?

a = ['1','2','3']
p = ''
b = ['Hi','Hello']
set_map = {
   '1': "l",
   '2': "m",
   '3': "n"
}
print('a[2] is:',a[2])
print('set_map[a[1]] is:',set_map[a[1]])

setattr(p, set_map[a[1]], b[1])

Result

a[2] is: 3
set_map[a[1]] is: m
Traceback (most recent call last):

    setattr(p, set_map[a[1]], b[1])
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'm'

Process finished with exit code 1

Please correct me.

Comment: `a[2]` is accessing the 3rd element in `a`.  If you take your `a` to be `['1', '2', '3']`, then `a[2] = '3'`.  You can then use this as the key for the `set_map` dictionary.  Notice that `set_map['3'] = 'n'`. 
 Note the difference between integers and strings.  '1' is a string, refering to the character 1, while `1` is an integer that refers to the number. Also, note that lists start at index 0, so if you want the second element of `a`, you would access it by `a[1]`.

Comment: Also, you can't set arbitrary attributes on a string type.  Are you trying to have `p = 'm'` in the end? or have `p.m = '3'`?  Try replacing p with an object, `class P: pass; p = P()`.

Comment: Super. Thanks you so much .

Comment: One last question. 

why does this error come TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable

I am passing line2 as variable and then using 
setattr(p, set_map[line2[1]], line2[2])

Comment: What type is `line2`?  Is it a set?  Try converting it to a list before accessing it.  when you try to access an element of a list, it's called 'subscripting'.  You can't do this with sets because sets (sets have no order, so 'the second element' doesn't make sense).

Comment: This is the code I am running:

class Dtp: #

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def dtp_method(cls, line_counter, line2):

        set_map = { '50', "repricer",
                    '90', "relinquised",
                    '573', "Other"
                  }
        setattr(p, set_map[line2[1]], line2[2])

Comment: ['DTP', '573', 'D8', '20160623'] is the line2 value.

Comment: Ahh, you need to use a colon `:` to separate key:value pairs in a dictionary. so `setmap = {'50': 'repricer', '90': 'relinquised', '573': 'Other'}`.  A dictionary's format is `{key:value, key:value}`.  If you only use commas, you've created a set with 6 elements.

Comment: Can we have the same thing for calling methods also 
example:
if line2[1]  = '1':
   a(line2)
elif line2[1] = '2':
   b(line2)
elif line2[1] = '3':
   c(line2)
and the list goes on. 
Can we have option where we can call the method based on the input in the line2 value.

Comment: That should work just fine.  Mixing the two will me harder though.  If it is just function calls, you can have your dictionary look like `dispatch = {'1': a, '2': b, '3': c}` and make calls like `dispatch['1'](line2)`